# Refering to a span of a li by clicking a button

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I'm trying to create a todo application using php, ajax and mysql.
There should be a button that, once clicked, deletes the item from the screen and the database, but I don't know how to refer that I want to delete a certain item.

(each item has a unique id in the database, also a text and the ID from the list that contains it)

An example of my html would be something like that:

```
 <ul id="list">
    <li class="i­tem">
        <div class="draggertab">
            <img src="imatges/botofletxa.jpg" width="30" height="30">
        </div>
        <div class="deletetab">
            <img src="imatges/botocreu.jpg" width="30" height="30">
        </div> <span>Buy some cookies</span> 
    </li>
</ul>
```

And I the javascript code would look like that:

```
  $('.deletetab').live('click', function () {
      var result = confirm("Are you sure?");
      if (result == true) {
          $(this).parent().remove();
      }
  });
```

But I don't know how to send (using ajax) the information to another php file (which connects to the database), or which variable should I use.

Sorry if that's a silly question, I'm new at programming!

Comment: live() has been deprecated and removed.

Comment: [jquery.ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) documentation will show you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know how you are rendering the list (ul), suppose it's a `foreach` loop or something of that kind. You can store each item's ID in a hidden field, so that you can access it's value from js:

```
 <ul id="list">
    <li class="i­tem">
        <input type="hidden" class="hidden_id" value="render_id_here" />
        <div class="draggertab">
            <img src="imatges/botofletxa.jpg" width="30" height="30">
        </div>
        <div class="deletetab">
            <img src="imatges/botocreu.jpg" width="30" height="30">
        </div> <span>Buy some cookies</span> 
    </li>
</ul>
```

js:

```
$('#list').on('click', '.deletetab', function(){
    var result = confirm("Are you sure?");

    if (result==true) {
         var parent = $(this).parent();

         $.ajax({
             type: 'POST',
             data: { idToDelete: parent.find('.hidden_id').val() }, //Find hidden ID field within parent div and read it's value
             url: 'delete.php'
         }).done(function() { //success callback
                parent.remove(); 
            }).fail(function(qXHR, textStatus) { //error callback
                alert('Server responded with error status ' + textSatus);
            });           
      }  
    });
```

On the server side you need to search the "idToDelete" parameter in posted data.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I get the idea, but I don't know how to put the right ID in your_ID_here...

Comment: Thank you! It works perfectly, but only with items that already exists, 'cause the new ones don't have the ID. How can I solve that?

Comment: You should return new ids from the server in respond to the post query, that adds new items. After that, insert new html fragment in success callback. How exactly you can retrieve the new id on the server depends on the backend technology you use. Try to google something like "MySQL last insert id" (I'm sure there's a function like this). Sorry, I'm not working with LAMP stack, can't advice definitely

Answer (score 0):

First, you can put your item's id on data-id attribute of each item.

```
<li class="item" data-id="{{ item_id"}}>
    // the rest of the html
</li>
```

Then the javascript

```
$('.deletetab').click(function() {
    var $this, $item;
    $this = $(this);
    $item = $this.closest('.item');
    if (confirm('Are you sure')) {
        $.post('url_to_delete.php', {id: $item.attr('data-id')}, function(data) {
            $item.remove();
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I can't make it work yet, but I get the idea. The problem is that that wouldn't work for new added items... Is there any way to insert a item in the database, get their id and return it?

Comment: you can use mysql_last_id to return the last inserted id, or PDO::lastInsertId if you use PDO.